# libgdx obj loader problen

Tags: android, libgdx

I am trying to make my first 3d game using Libgdx. However when I load my .obj file it does not look as I expect

On phone

[image]

and in Blender

[image]

I am loading with the following

```
@Override
public void create() {           
    InputStream stream = Gdx.files.internal("data/test.obj").read();
    model = ObjLoader.loadObj(stream, true);
    try {
        stream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         }        
}

@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update();
    camera.apply(Gdx.gl10);
    Gdx.gl10.glTranslatef(0.0f,0.0f,-3.0f);
    model.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: try with GL_TRIANGLE_FAN

Answer (score 0):

You need enable with GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D

```
Gdx.graphics.getGL10().glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    model.render();
Gdx.graphics.getGL10().glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```