# LIBGDX 3d .obj loader

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx

I'm starting and a newbie to use `libgdx` and try to load a `3d` model.

I just want to ask if `libgdx` have function or library that can load my `3d` model or should I create a `.obj` loader for me to load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be more specific about what file format you want to load, and what research you've done, if any.  That said, I think this what you're looking for: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g3d/loader/ObjLoader.java

For a bit of an example, see this SO question: [libgdx obj loader problen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944383/libgdx-obj-loader-problen)

Comment: im using blender for my 3d model and export it to .obj wave front..

my problem is how would i can load it to libgdx?

THANKS ill try to research more..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you check out this tutorial:
[Loading models with LibGDX](http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-models-using-libgdx/)
The new 3D API includes a built-in obj-loader.
Xoppa recently started writing tutorials. They are really straight-forward, and also contain a lot of useful information.